# Database Mirroring in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-mirroring

I have the Principal server and mirrored server placed on one VLAN and the witness server on another vlan. The port assigend to all these servers is 5022.

The problem we are facing is that the witness server though successfully being configured for database mirroring is not doing the automatic failover.

In the view Mirroring Monitor, the status under witnesss server shows disconnected for Mirrored server and is blank for Principal Server.

The project is in production so require urgent help!!

Comment: You might want to post this comment on www.ServerFault.com

Comment: If you require "urgent help" for a production issue then a forum is not the right place to get it. Time to call in outside help.

Comment: sounds like you have network issues between your witness & your principal/mirror

Answer (score 1):

There's a troubleshooting guide [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189127.aspx). I would try and telnet on port 5022 to see if you can connect to the mirror and primary from the witness.